# WSO2 - API Manager - Certificate issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Whenever we modify the filename in keystore.tls tag or we use the same keystore but different alias, both signin page of devportal and publisher are not opening and we are getting the below error in the log file:

> TID: [-1234] [authenticationendpoint] [2023-10-11 12:25:28,905] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/authenticationendpoint].[oauth2_login.do]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [oauth2_login.do] threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:324)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
> at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:1547)
> at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.filter.AuthenticationEndpointFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationEndpointFilter.java:87)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.filter.AuthenticationEndpointFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationEndpointFilter.java:188)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:89)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:116)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:165)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:111)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:106)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:67)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> TID: [-1234] [authenticationendpoint] [2023-10-11 12:25:28,905] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/authenticationendpoint].[default]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/authenticationendpoint] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [plugins/basicauth-extensions.jsp] at line [32]
> 29: request.setAttribute("errorMsg", AuthenticationEndpointUtil
> 30: .i18n(resourceBundle, "something.went.wrong.contact.admin"));
> 31: IdentityManagementEndpointUtil.addErrorInformation(request, e);
> 32: request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);
> 33: return;
> 34: }
> 35: File typingPatternRecorder = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("plugins/typing-dna.jsp"));
> Stacktrace:] with root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:324)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
> at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:1547)
> at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)

However, the console page is opening normally, can you please help?